# Find all records where table name matches partial string A and column name matches exact string B

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with hundreds of tables. e.g.

```
prefix_01_site_links
prefix_01_site_info
prefix_01_site_comments
prefix_02_site_links
prefix_02_site_info
prefix_02_site_comments
```

Inside all the site_info tables, are several columns e.g.

```
site_options
option_data
```

I need to find all the records where `site_options` exactly matches "site_url" and `option_data` partially matches "http:// and replace it with "https://"

That's easy enough but I don't want to go through each table because it is huge. Is there a way to first narrow the search down to only search within those tables with names partially matching  "site_info"?

Comment: such things need programing and loops, but can be done in stored procedudre if you want to stay only at mysql side.

Comment: @nbk ok I was hoping not to write any code since it's likely a one-off thing.

Comment: it is quite easy you make 1 functioning for the first table, out this with concat into a stirng and where come the flexible oart add add it . give it a try

Comment: "Hundreds of tables" -- Bad schema design, and you are finding out one of the reasons.

Comment: @RickJames Understand. It's not my choice unfortunately.

Comment: @nbk thanks! I'll give it a shot.